# Delete values from a vector under certain condition Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have vector `A` shown below, I want to subtract each value from the value before it and delete it if the difference exceeds a certain limit. For example,  `B = A(1:end-1) - A(2:end);` this get the difference, so `B=[-3 -32 -102]`, if the limit is between 50 and -50 then as shown from `B` the third value `-102` is outside the limit so this means that the third value in vector `A` should be deleted where its will be `A=[326 329 463]`, but I'm not sure how can I do this?

```
A=326
    329
    361
    463
```

Comment: Can you post what is your expected output B

Comment: `A([0 (diff(A)<threshold)])=[];` (if you want to input threshold as a positive number, you could do abs on the diff and then change the `<` to `>`).

Comment: @JohnGalt the expected output `B` is shown in my question, but I'll show what is the expected output of `A`

Comment: @Werner it gives an error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"

Comment: `A(logical([0 (abs(diff(A))>50)]))=[];`

Comment: @Werner thanks but this gives another error "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: Well, I declared A as `A=[326 329 361 463]`, if you have A as a column vector, simply do this: `A([false;(abs(diff(A))>50)])=[];` or `A([(abs(diff(A))>50);false])=[];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical indexing. The `diff` function will do exactly this operation `A(2:end)- A(1:end-1);` and compare its absolute value to the threshold, if greater, it will lead to true. Finally the leading false is to make the dimensions match because the diff will reduce the dimension by one, you can put it before or after the diff, depending if you want the index which is before the threshold limit to be deleted, or the one afterwards.

`A([false (abs(diff(A))>50)])=[];`

---

Please, pay attention to how your `A` vector is declared… if it is a column vector as `A=[326;329;361;463]`, the returned value by abs(diff(A)) will be an column vector as well, which means that you will need to use `;` operator to join the values. See what is being done step by step:

```
>> A=[326;329;361;463]             

A =

   326
   329
   361
   463

>> abs(diff(A))

ans =

     3
    32
   102

>> abs(diff(A))>50    

ans =

     0
     0
     1

>> [abs(diff(A))>50;false]

ans =

     0
     0
     1
     0

>> A([abs(diff(A))>50;false])

ans =

   361

>> A([abs(diff(A))>50;false])=[]

A =

   326
   329
   463
```

Comment: Answer doesn't seem to match.

Comment: @JohnGalt If he wants the 361 to be deleted, he can change the false place to `A([(abs(diff(A))>50) false])=[];`

Comment: @Werner still throws this error "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

Comment: @Werner you missed the semi-colon in your answer and this was causing the error. I've edited it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A=[326 329 361 463];
B=A(1:end-1) - A(2:end);
B(abs(B(1,:))>50)=A(abs(B(1,:))>50);
```

Gives

```
B=
    -3   -32   361
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wants to delete the third element from `A` `361` not replace it in `B`